# Compile git on shared host without zlib-devel

Tags: git, gcc, compilation, zlib

I'm trying to compile and install git on a shared RHEL5 host, but have no zlib-devel libraries installed. I've extracted the libraries from the RPM, but can't work out how to get make to recognise them. I get the following message:

> cache.h:17:18: error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Have tried the following:

```
CFLAGS='-I$HOME/root/usr/include -L$HOME/root/usr/lib64' make
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried setting

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH='$HOME/root/usr/include
```

Again, no luck. Any ideas? Needless to say, zlib.h is in $HOME/root/usr/include.

Comment: Edited question to post the error. Thanks!

Comment: Compile it on a host that does have it, then copy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated as I tried this on my own Linux machine**

You can use `CPPFLAGS` to specify your additional include directories.

```
CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/root/usr/include" ./configure
```

Also, if you are trying to make a 64-bit version, you do not specify linking to a location with 64-bit libraries to make it happen. Instead, you pass the `-m64` compiler flag in your `CFLAGS`, like this:

```
CFLAGS="-m64" CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/root/usr/include" ./configure
```

And if you have to specify additional non-standard library directories, use `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: zlib resides in the usual place - it's just the development libraries that I'm providing - so using --with-zlib doesn't help. And need to compile it so I can compile without other tools that aren't on the box.

Comment: @Submonoid: `--with-zlib` does work but you need the directory structure autotools expected. However, you can skip all that and use `CPPFLAGS` as per my edit.

Comment: Wonderful! I did `CFLAGS="-m64" CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/root/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/root/usr/lib64" ./configure --prefix=$HOME/root/usr` and everything seemed to work perfectly.