# Installing Git with non-root user account on RedHat

Tags: git, installation

I am attempting to install git on RedHat without root. install is failing because it can't find zlib.h

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239691/how-to-install-python-on-centos-without-root-privileges), which suggested installing anaconda, since it pulls down all the dependencies (including zlib.h, which is now at /home/foo/anaconda2/include/zlib.h)

I ran

```
./configure --prefix=/home/foo
```

because I want it installed in /home/foo/bin, but I still get

```
    CC credential-store.o
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:40:18: warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:42: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘z_stream’
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

How do I tell it to find zlib.h, and install everything in /home/foo/bin?

---

So, thanks to comment below I tried:

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/foo/share/perl5

wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
tar xzf ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz 
cd ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/foo
make PREFIX=/home/foo
make install PREFIX=/home/foo

wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JK/JKEENAN/ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56.tar.gz
tar -xzf ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56.tar.gz 
cd ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/foo
make PREFIX=/home/foo
make install PREFIX=/home/foo

CFLAGS="-m64" CPPFLAGS="-I /home/foo/anaconda2/include" LDFLAGS="-L /home/foo/anaconda2/lib" ./configure --prefix=/home/foo
make all doc info
```

Which got me closer:

```
    SUBDIR perl
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX='/home/foo' INSTALL_BASE='' --localedir='/home/foo/share/locale'
Generating a Unix-style perl.mak
Writing perl.mak for Git
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
    * new perl-specific parameters
    ...
    * new Python interpreter location
    ..
    LINK git
    BUILTIN git-add
    ...
    SUBDIR git-gui
GITGUI_VERSION = 0.20.GITGUI
    * new locations or Tcl/Tk interpreter
    ...
    SUBDIR gitk-git
    * new Tcl/Tk interpreter location
    GEN gitk-wish
    ...
    SUBDIR perl
    ...
Manifying 9 pod documents
    SUBDIR templates
    MSGFMT po/build/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
/bin/sh: msgfmt: command not found
make: *** [po/build/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo] Error 127
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The clean way : ask a sudoer or root credentials ownet to install `zlib-devel`package.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105839/compile-git-on-shared-host-without-zlib-devel

Comment: Getting a sudoer to do it is not one of my options

Comment: @glenfant Thank you, that got me closer, but not all the way

Answer (score 0):

The solution to building git w/o root:

Install Anaconda (in this case, in /home/foo/anaconda2/)

Install needed perl

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/foo/share/perl5

wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
tar xzf ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz 
cd ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/foo
make PREFIX=/home/foo
make install PREFIX=/home/foo

wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JK/JKEENAN/ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56.tar.gz
tar -xzf ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56.tar.gz 
cd ExtUtils-ModuleMaker-0.56
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/foo
make PREFIX=/home/foo
make install PREFIX=/home/foo
```

Download git. Extract and switch to directory

```
make configure
CFLAGS="-m64" CPPFLAGS="-I /home/foo/anaconda2/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/foo/anaconda2/lib" ./configure --prefix=/home/foo
make NO_GETTEXT=1 all 
make install NO_GETTEXT=1 all 

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/foo/anaconda2/lib
```

I would have liked to compile doc and info as well, but I got bugs that I couldn't immediately fix, and I need to actually USE git now.